# UE5: Adding Actor Instances to an Array

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5

Using UE5, I'm making a Mario Party board. I have the base "Tile" class and children classes for each tile. For each tile, I wanted to have an array of "Previous" and "Next" tiles. In my Board blueprint, I've set up a path of tiles and I want to link the tiles together by using these arrays, but I can't seem to do it. The goal here is for each tile to have a reference to the next and previous tile(s).

If I make the arrays of "Tile" class, I cannot see the array in the details panel while a tile is selected in the Board blueprint. The only way the arrays show up is if I make it "Actor Component", but this is not what I want, and neither can I add tiles to that array.

I'd appreciate some insight or some help on this.

[Variables in Tile class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBvvg.png)

[View of variables for a selected tile in the Board blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfsiX.png)

Here, you can see what I've attempted and results.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please, clarify the question. Which help do you need? Can you be more specific? Which step is blocking your progress?

Comment: I want to access the array of "Tile" objects per instance "Tile" inside of the "Board" blueprint, but these arrays are not appearing in the details panel of each instance of "Tile". The images are examples of what I mean.